# How to create a custom activation function for CNN using Tensorflow 2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have used activation functions such as ReLU, tanh, and sigmoid activation. However, now I want to create a simple custom activation function. 
Suppose I want the following activation -

```
if x > 0: 
    return 1.2*x;
else:
    return 0.01*x;
```

How to write the activation function for such an activation function in tensorflow and apply it to all the hidden layers of CNN?

Comment: See [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/58884/how-to-create-custom-activation-functions-in-keras-tensorflow).